# Azure PowerShell Set-AzureRmSqlDatabase hangs/very slow

Tags: powershell, azure

I am working on a script that clones a database from production resource group and Premium pricing tier to QA resource group and Standard pricing tier.

**Step 1** using New-AzureRmSqlDatabaseCopy clone the production database to qa.
       Source is in "Elastic Premium" pricing tier and the clone is in "Premium 
P2" pricing tier.

**Step 2** Delete bunch of old records ( Invoke-Sqlcmd ...-InputFile ...) because in QA database we don't need these.

**Step 3** lower the pricing tier down using Set-AzureRmSqlDatabase ... -RequestedServiceObjectiveName "S0"

For some reason the step to lower the pricing tier just hangs.(45+ minutes)
By adding a Start-Sleep for 3 minutes after 2nd step, the 3rd step seems to eventually complete in 20+ minutes. 
In the meanwhile, in the Azure portal I see the message

```
 Updating database pricing tier from P2 Premium to S0 Standard
```

Step 2 takes the database size from ~10GB to ~5GB. Not sure if this has any bearing on the issue.

I have tried sqlcmd instead of Invoke-Sqlcmd but had same issue.

Any idea what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

After looking around a bit, found following explanation

a 250 GB database that is changing to, from, or within a Standard service tier, should complete within 6 hours

at  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-scale-up-powershell.

So, the amount of time taken is proportional to the database size.